# Why do I get different value from 'form.$invalid' and the $invalid property of 'form'?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to disable a button base on the form's status($invalid), after I set all the values in the form to be null, I found that if I whrite: `console.log('$scope.assignNewForm.$invalid: ' + $scope.assignNewForm.$invalid);` It will give out put as **false**, but if I write: `console.log($scope.assignNewForm);` I can find the $invalid property of the form which is **true**. This happens at the same time.

posted my code below:

```
$scope.questionnaireTitleSelected = function(questionnaireTitle) {

    $scope.assignForm.recipientType = null;
    $scope.assignForm.assigneeName = null;
    resetErrorState();
    $scope.flags.readOnly = false;

    $scope.recipientTypes = _.where($scope.questionnaires, {
      questionnaireTitle: questionnaireTitle
    });

    disabledAssignBtn();
  };

function disabledAssignBtn() {
    if (!$scope.assignNewForm) {
      return;
    }
    console.log($scope.assignNewForm.$invalid);
    console.log($scope.assignNewForm);

    $scope.flags.disabledAssignBtn = $scope.assignNewForm.$invalid || $scope.assignedError || $scope.flags.noQuestionnaires;
  }
```

and the result:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0sfF.png)

Comment: add your code this can not be happen.. need to see your code.

Comment: updated question.

Comment: Okay to check the changing values in your form you should use $dirty.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, `$invalid` property of the object changed before you could open the object on the console. That happens because the properties of the object are evaluated the time you collapse it.

The `i` icon next to object says `Value below was evaluated just now`, when you hover on it.